# Microsoft Flow Execution Order

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, office365api, power-automate

I have created a bunch of short flows that act on a single SharePoint list item to reduce complexity, but I've run into a problem with the order in which they execute. I think I could best explain this with an example, so please see below:

Let's say there are three flows, ***SetTitle***, ***SetPermissions***, and ***SendEmail*** (sends an email based on the new value after a column changes). Ideally, *SetPermissions* would run first, then *SendEmail*, and finally *SetTitle* since it modifies the item. That modification is a problem because it adds a version to Version History, which I am checking in the *SendEmail* flow to see if the value of a column changed.

Currently, however, *SetTitle* sometimes runs first, which breaks *SendEmail* because now the most recently displaced version does not contain a record of the column change that happened two versions ago.

I would like to avoid creating additional columns in the item to track column changes or emails sent, because we're creating these flows to avoid that messy complexity.

I'm hoping that there is some hidden execution order option somewhere, because as I said, I don't really want to create extra columns or trigger flows based on HTTP calls. Of course, what I'm doing now isn't working, so I understand that I may have to compromise.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think what you are looking for is possible tbh.

I know you said you do not want to create more columns, but the only solution that I can think of requires only 1 extra column to be created. Use that to run the flows in the right order.

For example, if there are two flows: f1 and f2, set the default value of the new column(let's call it 'stage') to 0. Then, add a condition to f1 so it only runs when the stage is 0 and also updates the column to 1. Then f2 also has an initial condition check and runs only when 'Stage' is '1' and also sets 'Stage' to '2'.

Hope this helps.